# Universal Deep Linking with redirects

Tags: ios

I was wondering if it was possible to get Universal Deep Linking working with redirects that open up Safari first. I've successfully gotten deep linking to work when doing a normal link to the site, but when it is behind a link that is created by a marketing company, that link opens up Safari first, then opens the mobile web browser and not the app itself.

Is it possible to go from a redirect in Safari to the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question was answered on the Apple Developer forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26760?q=universal%20deep%20linking

The answer, as of right now, is that Apple does not support Universal Deep Linking from a redirect. A side note, this issue does not seem to exist if you tap the originating link from within Safari.

Comment: So I guess we should use url-schemes (custom-scheme://) for deep linking instead of universal links, looks like those are working even when we get redirected from within Safari.